# How can I check if a group does not have users and delete it?

Tags: linux, scripting, group

How can I check if a group does not have users and delete it?

I'm doing a bash linux script, and I need to delete a group with the groupdel command, but I have to validate that the group I'm going to remove is empty, which does not have users.

This is what I have done:

```
  bajagroup () {
printf "\ nEnter the name of the group to delete: \ n"
read -r remove group
[ -n $ deletegroup ] && groupdel $ deletegroup
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                 echo "The group was not deleted from the system. Please try again."
         else
                 echo "The group was deleted from the system."
fi
sleep 3
}
```

Something similar to the delgroup command with the --only-if-empty option, but with the groupdel command.

Example: `delgroup --only-if-empty`

Comment: It's not sufficient to look at *users*, but at *files* which happen to use that group (and happen to be accessible).  Deleting the group gives you just a number for the group-id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the members of a group in Linux isn't as easy as one might think. In my opinion the easiest way would be using the `lid` command. Install it using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libuser
```

then you should try if it works using

```
lid -g root
```

If it says command not found try

```
/usr/sbin/libuser-lid -g root
```

And for your script

```
bajagroup () {
printf "\n Enter the name of the group to delete: \n"
read -p groupname #the variable has to be one word(normally)
deletegroup=$(lid -g $groupname)
[ -z $deletegroup ] && groupdel $deletegroup #between $ and the name no space
```

**Edit**

Since you can't install the package I wrote a little script that should solve your problem

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter groupname here: " groupname #Takes the input and save it to the variable groupname
gid=$(cat /etc/group | grep ^"$groupname": | cut -d":" -f3) #get the content of /etc/group (list of every group with groupid) | search for the line that starts with $groupname: (That means if a group name is Test, Test1 or 1Test wouldn't be matched) | get the groupid
member=$(cat /etc/passwd | cut -d":" -f4 | grep -x "$gid") #get the content of /etc/passwd (list of all users with some extra information like the attached gid) | get the part with the gid | grep the line that is exactly $gid
[ -z $member ] && groupdel $groupname #if $member is empty then delete that group
```

This is the base you need. You can change the ending and beginning to your needs.

Comment: Great, thank you so much, the problem is that I have to run this script on a computer with OpenSuse and it is an old version. Therefore, I can not install that package on the computer.

Comment: @user240991 I wrote a script that should substitute the package.